# How do I take a string, convert said string to bianary, and then take each 1 or 0 and add it as a value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, converters

I am doing some tests with grids in java, and how to generate them with 1s and 0s, 1s being [+] and 0s being [ ].

(TLDR):

I want to be able to take in words(s), convert that to bianary, and add each individual 1 and 0 to an array

The way I have the grids set up is:

```java
        // code that tells method how to generate the grid
         int[] GRIDCODE3x3_1 = new int[]{
                  0, 1, 0,
                  1, 1, 1,
                  0, 1, 0
          };
         public void fillGridSpec(int[] x) {
         System.out.println("\n");
         int count = 0;
             String gridLine = " ";
             for(int p = 0; p < gridHeight; p++) {
                 gridLine = " ";
                 String[] gridArray = new String[gridWidth];
                 for(int q = 0; q < gridWidth; q++) {
                     if(x[count] == 1) {
                         gridArray[q] = "[+] ";
                         count++;
                     } else {              
                         gridArray[q] = "[ ] ";
                         count++;
                     }
                     gridLine += gridArray[q];
                 }
                 System.out.println(gridLine);
             }
        }
```

Output would be:

```
[ ] [+] [ ]
[+] [+] [+]
[ ] [+] [ ]
```

With that out of the way I want to give an example of what I want it to do.

Lets say the string is *a*

The bianary for this is `01100001`, what I need this to turn into is `0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1` so the output is

```
[ ] [+] [+] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [+]
```

but I also need it to be repeatable, as in if the String is Hello World

(bianary):

`01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100`

(the amount of commas here is redundant so I'll take it you know what I need to convert this to, and how the output works)

If you need any clarification with what I am asking, ask it in the comments and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: *If you need any clarification with what I am asking* - yes what are you asking?

Comment: I want to take in word(s), convert that to bianary, then take each individual 1 and 0 and add it to an array

Comment: That is not a question.  What is `x` in `if(x[count] == 1) {` ?

Comment: It’s the value of the GRIDCODE3x3_1 in the [count] position. I.e. a 1 or 0

Comment: Lemme re-phrase the question: how do I take a string, convert said string to bianary, and then take each 1 or 0 and add it as a value in an array.

Comment: The array at the top is an example of what goes into the code, just to give an example of how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want according to your subject is as follows:

```
String str = "Hello World";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    String binStr = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(str.charAt(i))).replace(' ', '0');

    int[] intArray = new int[binStr.length()];
    for (int j = 0; j < binStr.length(); j++) {
        intArray[j] = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(binStr.charAt(j)));

        // This also works 
        //intArray[j] = Character.getNumericValue(binStr.charAt(j));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
}
```

**Console output**

> [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
>   [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
>   [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
>   [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>   [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
>   [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>   [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
>   [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
>   [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: I get a nullPointerException when I try and change the input String

Comment: @Rellik What kind of string did you change to? Could you give an example?

Comment: I changed it to “bruh” I’ll give the full example in a few minutes, I’m out at the moment

Comment: I put your code into a method called Convert() which takes in a string as a parameter, when I try and call on the array produced it comes up as null. Specifically:                                                                                    `System.out.println("enter a word");
   for(int i = 0; i < onerun.length(); i++) {
    String PLACEHOLDER1 = IO.nextLine();
    word = IO.nextLine();
   }
   Grid inputTest2 = new Grid(8, word.length());
   Converter.Convert(word);
   inputTest2.fillGridSpec(Converter.getCode());`.

Comment: @Rellik It seems the `word` may be null while passing it to `Converter.Convert(word);`. Have you checked it first?

Comment: @Rellik If you know what the `word` is, you can directly test it with my code snippet. But I don't think a `nullPointerException` will be thrown if `str` is not null. Or can you point out which line throws this exception?

Comment: it is 116 for me, the nullpointerexception comes when i am going to read the array, `if(x[count] == 1) { ... `

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what you asking, but

```
String a = "01001000";
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

for (char c: a.toCharArray()) {
    buf.append("[");
    if (c == '1') {
        buf.append("+");
    }
    buf.append("] ");
}

System.out.println(buf);
```

**edit**

If the input is a char, it can be converted to a binary String like

```
    String a = Integer.toBinaryString('a');
    System.out.println(a);
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c: a.toCharArray()) {
        buf.append("[");
        if (c == '1') {
            buf.append("+");
        }
        else {
            buf.append(" ");
        }
        buf.append("] ");
    }

    System.out.println(buf);
```

Comment: I think you should add `else {buf.append(" ");}` because 0 will be `[ ]` - a space not a empty string.

Comment: I think this should work, and I think I figured out the misunderstanding, string is a is not string a..., but is String <stringname> = “a”; and the bianary value of “a” is 01100001